# storing split values from excel to mysql in two rows

Tags: mysql

I ahve excel sheet with the following  columns

```
Sam/Simon   Date    Store   Customer name   Original Order Number

Simon    09/11/2014 Bristol Cr  Car        20089691/ 26089697
```

I need to store these infomration in 2 rows in tables

```
Simon    09/11/2014 Bristol Cr  Car        20089691/
Simon    09/11/2014 Bristol Cr  Car        26089697
```

I need to know the table structure. Split comma separated values from one column to 2 rows in the results and exporting them from excel to mysql.

the actual  table structure is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE "tblOrderR" (
  "intOrderRemedialId" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "intOrderId" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "intOrderRemedialGivenPence" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "intRequestedById" smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "intAuthorizedById" smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,


  PRIMARY KEY ("intOrderRemedialId"),
  KEY "tblOrderRemedial" ("intOrderId"),
  KEY "tblOrderRemedial_ibfk_2" ("intRequestedById"),
  KEY "tblOrderRemedial_ibfk_3" ("intAuthorizedById"),
  CONSTRAINT "tblOrderRemedial_ibfk_1" FOREIGN KEY ("intOrderId") REFERENCES "tblOrder" ("intOrderId"),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Order Remedial Information';
```

Comment: And what's your final question ?

Comment: while importing from excel has 20089691/ 26089697 in one rows how to export them in 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be:

1) Split out "Original Order Number" Excel column into two separate columns using [TEXT TO COLUMNS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-names-by-using-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-2cd989db-2b1f-4d89-b17b-534250ff9905)

2) Save data in csv format

3) Load data into a staging table that looks something like this

```
samSimon,date,store,customerName,originalOrder1,originalOrder2
```

4) Run two inserts into your final table: one with originalOrder1 and a second one with originalOrder2. For example:

```
insert into tblOrderR (columns) 
select samSimon,date,store,customerName,originalOrder1 from stagingTable;

insert into tblOrderR (columns) 
select samSimon,date,store,customerName,originalOrder2 from stagingTable;
```

Very pseudo-code answer but hopefully you get the gist of it!

Comment: how to ignore those split values row on mysql  insert script.

Answer (score 0):

Just import two times.

First time (example code, you might have to adjust the one or the other thing):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/excel.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(column1, column2, @my_variable)
SET column3 = SUBSTRING(@my_variable FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('/', @my_variable));
```

Second time:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/excel.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(column1, column2, @my_variable)
SET column3 = SUBSTRING(@my_variable FROM LOCATE('/', @my_variable) + 1);
```

Relevant manual pages:

- [string functions like substring() and locate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)
- [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)